# bumblebee2 or bumblebee1394, this is the question

Tags: ros, bumblebee2, camera-drivers, bumblebee

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi all,

I want to acquire images from a Bumblebee2 stereo camera device (IEEE1394 HW interface), in order to publish them , so they could be available for other nodes. Browsing the existing software at ros.org, I've found two packages that can be useful to do it:

```
 http://www.ros.org/browse/details.php?name=bumblebee1394

 http://www.ros.org/browse/details.php?name=bumblebee2
```

So, my question is, can anyone give me an advice / comment about why using one package or the other ?

I'm using ROS-electric.

Thanks, community help is very valuable !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11492/bumblebee2-or-bumblebee1394,-this-is-the-question./) by [Andreu](https://answers.ros.org/users/932/andreu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 169 on 2011-10-10

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i have been using a slightly changed version of the bumblebee2 node.
the changed i made to the node can be found in this answer: http://answers.ros.org/question/1118/bumblebee2-640x480-under-diamondback?answer=1894#1894.

these fixes work for diamondback, im not sure if they work under electric (it probably works unless some messages have changed by a lot).

(yes i know this is quite an old question, just posting for anyone with the same question)

---

Originally posted by [Bram van de Klundert](https://answers.ros.org/users/392/bram-van-de-klundert/) with karma: 241 on 2011-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-12-12**:
Electric should probably work, too. I don't recall any significant camera interface changes for that release.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We tried both packages and had our problems with them. The result was, that we did not get our bumblebee running with any of this packages and created our own minimalistic ros node which uses the triclops software from point grey for most tasks and just publishes the resulting images in ROS.

I fear that is not really helpful, but that was our result... problems ranged from wrong DC image mode to not compatible with diamondback...

---

Originally posted by [Achim](https://answers.ros.org/users/1188/achim/) with karma: 390 on 2011-10-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lure_Angler](https://answers.ros.org/users/3422/lure_angler/) on 2013-02-21**:
Hello Achim, I was wondering if you could provide a link to the minimalistic ros node for bumblebee 2 that you mentioned in this answer. I would like to use it for a Autonomous Underwater Vehicle that I'm using the Bumblebee 2 with. Many thanks. =)

**Comment by [Achim](https://answers.ros.org/users/1188/achim/) on 2013-02-21**:
I fear that code is not open source. :(
Also it has it's own issues... it's using the triclops libraries which tend to crash on 64bit systems.